# Getting syntax error unexpected msg in PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a forgot my password page on a website and I am trying to get messages to show to alert the user that to check their email. However I am getting this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"msg"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in URL on line 21

PHP code

```
require_once('config1.php');

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM zz_login WHERE email='$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $token = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890";
        $token = str_shuffle($token);
        $token = substr($token, start, 0, length, 10);

        $sql = "UPDATE zz_login SET token='$token',
                            tokenExpire=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
                            WHERE email='$email' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

        exit (json_encode(array("status" => 1 "msg" => 'Please check your email inbox!'))); 
    } else 
        exit (json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => 'Please check your inputs'))); 
}
```

Line 21 is: **exit (json_encode(array("status" => 1 "msg" => 'Please check your email inbox!'))); **

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please read php manual about arrays instead of posting this.

Comment: You forgot a comma , json_encode(array("status" => 1, "msg" => 'Please check your email inbox!')))

Comment: You should have found by yourself you are missing a ","... With the error line number, no need to create a post here, please!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a comma on line 21:

`exit (json_encode(array("status" => 1 "msg" => 'Please check your email inbox!')));`

should be

`exit (json_encode(array("status" => 1, "msg" => 'Please check your email inbox!')));`

Comment: I am an idiot, thank you!!

Comment: Ha, no problem, sometimes we overlook the simple things.